# Doubles quotes character change after type in MacOS Notes.app

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

My problem is, when I type "double quotes" in Notes app (MacOS), the quotes changed for other character, so, if I try to copy the code for paste anywhere, the code are invalid.

- Double quotes: "
- Notes double quotes: “

I use Notes.app like "a Gist".

Why this is happening and how to solve that?

[image: double quotes changed after type]

Comment: Turn off Smart Quotes in the Edit menu…

Comment: @deceze thank you so much :) works

Answer (score 3):

Disable "Smart Quotes and dashes"

[image]

and change the input to U.S (Remove US International) in case you are having the problem where a quote changes a character to a special character

[image]